# How to use more than 10 tab stops in bmatrix or other amsmath matrix environments?

Tags: math-mode, amsmath, matrices

I'm using `bmatrix` environment from the `amsmath` package, and I'm trying to do something like this:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}

 \begin{document}
     \begin{equation}
         \begin{bmatrix}
             1 & 2 & 3 & 4 & 5 & 6 & 7 & 8 & 9 & 10 & 11\\
         \end{bmatrix}
    \end{equation}
 \end{document}
```

However, pdfLaTeX returns an error: "Extra alignment tab has been changed to \cr", and in the output the extra element is moved to the next row. (If I remove one element, then it works perfectly fine). I guess this means that I've hit some hard limit on the number of tab stops in a matrix. Is there a way to change this?

The elements in the matrix are short and could fit perfectly on a single row.

Comment: Funny enough, I looked once more after I got an answer to the question, and this http://www.latex-community.org/forum/viewtopic.php?f=46&t=5996 popped up, answered by @Stefan Kottwitz a year ago. Wish I could give him some rep for that!

Answer (score 123, accepted):

Googling "10 columns" together with "tex" and "halign" lead me to [this](http://www.ocf.berkeley.edu/~latex/f09/files/reader.pdf) document, where it is explained that, e.g.,

```
\setcounter{MaxMatrixCols}{20}
```

enables you to use 20 columns.

Comment: This is documented in the footnote on page 8 of the `amsmath` manual.

Comment: Which leads to the question: Why is there even a hard limit?

Comment: It's worth nothing that, as explained in the document, this line of code should "precede the start of the matrix environment".

Comment: Which leads to another question: why is the error so uninformative?

Answer (score 7):

Yet another method is to use the `array` construct from `amsmath` package.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\begin{document}

\begin{equation}
\left[ \begin{array}{@{}*{11}{c}@{}}
     1 & 2 & 3 & 4 & 5 & 6 & 7 & 8 & 9 & 10 & 11\\
\end{array} \right]
\end{equation}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: If you want to emulate `bmatrix`, you should use `\begin{array}{@{}*{11}{c}@{}}`. The `*{11}{c}` is just a convenient way to avoid counting the number of `c`'s; the important thing is `@{}` at the sides, to kill the automatically inserted padding.

Comment: @egreg  Many thanks, I was just thinking of adding two `\!\!` around the `array`, but your suggestion is much more elegant.

Comment: The `bmatrix` environment indeed does `\hspace{-\arraycolsep}` on either ends (it's one of the reasons why the `MaxMatrixCols` counter is needed).

Comment: Isn't the `array` construct native instead of from the `amsmath` package?