# Problem with matrix (too many alignment tabs)

Tags: matrices

I can not see any problem here. I guess that some problem with *encoding* or *end of line* could be the reason.

See the image.

[image]

**The code.**

```
\documentclass[11pt,a4paper]{report}
\usepackage[latin1]{inputenc}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\begin{document}

\[J_{i} = \begin{bmatrix}%
x_{i}   & 1         & 0         & \cdots    & 0         & | & 0         & 0         & 0         & \cdots & 0        &  & \cdots      \\%
%0      & x_{i}     & 1         & \cdots    & 0         & | & 0         & 0         & 0         & \cdots & 0        &  & \cdots      \\
%\vdots & \vdots    & \vdots    & \ddots    & \vdots    & | & \vdots    & \vdots    & \vdots    & \ddots & \vdots   &  & \cdots      \\
%0      & 0         & 0         & \cdots    & 1         & | & 0         & 0         & 0         & \cdots & 0        &  & \cdots      \\
%0      & 0         & 0         & \cdots    & x_{i}     & | & 0         & 0         & 0         & \cdots & 0        &  & \cdots      \\
%-      & -         & -         & - - -     & -         & - & -         & -         & -         & - - -  & -        &  &             \\
%0      & 0         & 0         & \cdots    & 0         & | & x_{i}     & 1         & 0         & \cdots & 0        &  & \cdots      \\
%0      & 0         & 0         & \cdots    & 0         & | & 0         & x_{i}     & 1         & \cdots & 0        &  & \cdots      \\
%\vdots     & \vdots    & \vdots    & \ddots    & \vdots    & | & \vdots    & \vdots    & \vdots    & \ddots & \vdots   &  & \cdots      \\
%0      & 0         & 0         & \cdots    & 0         & | & 0         & 0         & 0         & \cdots & 1        &  & \cdots      \\
%0      & 0         & 0         & \cdots    & 0         & | & 0         & 0         & 0         & \cdots & x_{i}    &  & \cdots      \\
%-      & -         & -         & - - -     & -         & - & -         & -         & -         & - - -  & -        &  &             \\
%\vdots     & \vdots    & \vdots    & \vdots    & \vdots    &   & \vdots    & \vdots    & \vdots    & \vdots & \vdots   &  & \ddots
\end{bmatrix}
\]
\end{document}
```

Comment: Possible duplicate: [How to use more than 10 tab stops in `\bmatrix`?](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/3519/5764)

Comment: @Werner, I can not believe!!! I had never heard about this kind of problem. Thanks so much. I'll delete the post.