# Extra alignment tab?

Tags: errors

I used

```
\begin{matrix}
\ldots & 1 & 0 & 0 & 2 & 1 & | & 2 & 0 & 0 & 1 & \ldots \\
\ldots &   &   &   &   & 0 & | & 1  &   &   &   &
\end{matrix}
```

But Latex says:

```
Extra alignment tab has been changed to \cr.
<recently read> \endtemplate
```

Where is my mistake?

Answer (score 3):

See [How to use more than 10 tab stops in \bmatrix?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/3519/how-to-use-more-than-10-tab-stops-in-bmatrix), but probably you want something else:

```
\[
\begin{array}{@{} *{6}{c} | *{5}{c} @{}}
\dots & 1 & 0 & 0 & 2 & 1 & 2 & 0 & 0 & 1 & \dots \\
\dots &   &   &   &   & 0 & 1  &   &   &   &
\end{array}
\]
```

[image]

Compare with the output of

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\setcounter{MaxMatrixCols}{12}
\begin{document}
\[
\begin{matrix}
\dots & 1 & 0 & 0 & 2 & 1 & | & 2 & 0 & 0 & 1 & \dots \\
\dots &   &   &   &   & 0 & | & 1  &   &   &   &
\end{matrix}
\]
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: IMHO, this is very curious "feature" of LaTeX's matrix: the limit to max 10 columns. The matrix can be declared using `\halign` primitive with unlimited number of columns.

Comment: @wipet The problem is removing the padding at either side, while keeping all the features of `array` that's not simply `\halign`.

Comment: This is not simply `\halign` but it is implemented by `\halign` and it can be implemented more general. But I understand that this is for somebody problem.

Comment: @wipet The main author of `amsmath` was a very skilled TeX programmer and he chose this approach. I'd be wary of offending his memory. If you think you can do better, why don't you offer your services to AMS or at least propose a different implementation that behaves the same?