# Showing one row of a matrix in two lines

Tags: matrices

My matrix has 34 columns and I want to show one of its rows. I've tried the below code but I get error.

```
\[
\begin{split}
[\begin{matrix}
0.5932  &  0.5932  &  0.5932  &  0.5932  &  0.5932  &  0.5932  &  0.5932  &    0.5932  &  8.9378  &  6.3859  &  0.5932  &  0.5932  &  0.5932  &  8.8536  &   8.9026  &  8.9378  &  0.5932\end{matrix}\\
&\qquad\qquad  \begin{matrix}
0.5932  &  8.9026  &  8.9378  &  8.9353  &  0.5932  &  8.8685  &  8.9451  & 0.5932  &  0.5932  &  6.3718  &  6.3859  &  6.4426  &  8.1686  &  6.9617  &         7.5497  &  8.2024  &  0.5932 \end{matrix}]
\end{split} 
\]
```

How should I solve it?
The error is : ! Extra alignment tab has been changed to \cr.

Comment: I don't see 34 columns. Nor do I see a matrix with multiple rows. Could you make your question a bit clearer?

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SE! Since the code you provided shows 17 cells and I see two matrices, maybe you meant 34 *cells* (17*2=34). So you have two rows, so to speak, with 17 cells each. Not sure why you're building the matrix like that, but apparently the error appears if you define more than 10 columns (that's what Matrix defines). So you need to add `\setcounter{MaxMatrixCols}{<YourColsNumber>}` as stated in [another question](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/3519/4778), which makes this question a duplicate. But at least your problem is solved. :)