# Python array to txt or csv to latex

Tags: matrices, csv

I'm new at Latex and I have a problem, I have an array in Python and I want to paste that array as a matrix in Latex in a simple way.
In Python I have:

```
np.savetxt("matrix.csv", matrizfake, delimiter=' & ', fmt='%10.5f' ,newline=' \\\\\n')
```

That creates a csv file with the data of the matriz array.
How the code should be, if I want to read that file, and print it as a matrix in Latex.

Thanks for your help, excuse my english.

Comment: Hi, welcome. `\[ \begin{matrix} \input{matrix.csv} \end{matrix} \]`?

Comment: I tried that at first, but I get the following error: ! Extra alignment tab has been changed to \cr.

Comment: Please prepare a full minimal example so that we can see what happens. It seems  that `\\` is not printed or you have some short row.

Comment: Why didn't you say that you tried that then? You probably have more than 10 columns: https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/3519