# Problem in horizontal vector width

Tags: math-mode, matrices, arrows, vector

Good morning everyone, I have a problem using the command

```
$$\mathbf{u} = \begin{Bmatrix} u_i & v_i & w_i & \theta_i & \phi_i & \psi_i & u_j & v_j & w_j & \theta_j & \phi_j  & \psi_j \end{Bmatrix}^T$$
```

In particular, in the compilation output, the vector becomes a matrix with two rows: \phi_j  and \psi_j change line and form an other row. Can someone help me?

[image]

Comment: Welcome! Add `\setcounter{MaxMatrixCols}{12}` before the matrix. `\setcounter{MaxMatrixCols}{20}` would also work.

Comment: Welcome! This post might be helpful: https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/3521/109339

Comment: It worked! Thanks a lot