# Matrix row gets printed in 2 separate rows

Tags: beamer, matrices

I want to write a 12x12 matrix in beamer but the last 2 row elements get printed in another line. I've only included one of the rows here to demonstrate the problem but I have the same issue with the entire matrix.

I tried scaling the equation but it didn't help.

```
\begin{frame}{Major Diatonic Matrix}
    $$
    S = \begin{pmatrix}
1 & 1 & 0 & 1 & 0 & 1 & 0 & 1 & 1 & 0 & 1 & 0 \\
\end{pmatrix}
    $$
\end{frame}
```

[image]

And this is how it looks like within the frame:

[image: The Entire Frame]

Comment: Are you compiling this on Overleaf?

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SE.

Comment: @Werner Yes I am

Comment: Overleaf compiles through the error that is being reported. That error indicates that you can't have more than 10 columns. Well, you can, but you have to adjust `MaxMatrixCols`: `\setcounter{MaxMatrixCols}{12}`; see [How to use more than 10 tab stops in `bmatrix` or other `amsmath` matrix environments?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/3519/5764)

Comment: Never ignore errors, the PDF is not intended to be usable after an error.